# How do you solve a relational database paradox?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a website in progress where users create posts in a feed, and may have many feeds. Their profile will display a default feed of their choosing.

The 3 tables in this paradox are "accounts", "profiles", and "feeds".
An entry in profiles contains additional information about a user. This is in a separate table because it may be modified more often, and many queries use the accounts table without needing this information.

A field in accounts (profile) must reference a profile. I've done this, instead of having profiles reference accounts, because otherwise an account could exist without a profile. A profile existing without an account would be the result of a deactivated account (provided the user explicitly chose not to have their profile removed from the site).

A field in profiles (default_feed) must reference a feed. This may be changed often, and isn't needed by most queries, so this seems a sensible place for this data.

A field in feeds must reference an account; all feeds have a creator.

You may be able to see my problem already, but I'll elaborate:
I can't make an account without making a profile, which I can't make without making a feed, which I can't make without making an account, etc...

Must I give up the functionality of profiles for deactivated accounts (which wouldn't be a huge deal, but I'd like to know if there's another way), or is there a sensible trick that will allow me to solve the paradoxical nature of this relationship?

EDIT: I've realized I could simply set the default_feed field so it's allowed to be null, and have the application handle this special case (which should never happen anyway, since a feed is created with the account) with a "this user has no default feed" message. I'd still like to know if I've missed a more creative solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to break the dependency is to make default_feed in profile nullable.

- Start by creating a profile with the default feed set to null
- Create the account that references that profile.
- Once the account is set up, create the default feed with the account that has been created as owner.

Comment: Just a minute after my edit. It seems to be the perfect solution though.